# How to sort two structs with one common variable

Tags: swift, sorting, struct

I have two structs in Swift like this:

```
struct Friend {
    id: Int
    name: String
    biography: String
    profilePicURL: String
}

struct ProfileViews {
    id: Int
    views: Int
}
```

I am trying to sort an array of Friends (`[Friend]`) based on the amount of views for the profile (`[ProfileViews]`). How can I do this based on the id, which is the same in both structs? The catch is, sometimes both structs won't match. It can be, for example, that a certain Friend doesn't have ProfileViews yet. For example:

```
Friend(id: 1, name: "PennyWise", biography: "Lorem ipsum", "test.jpg")
Friend(id: 2, name: "Bob", biography: "Dolar sit amet", "test2.jpg")
Friend(id: 3, name: "Dylan", biography: "Yes we can!", "test3.jpg")

ProfileViews(id: 1, views: 23)
ProfileViews(id: 3, views: 12)
```

I then want to order the `[Friend]` array based on the views, so id 1, id 3, id 2. How can I do this? I am aware of the `sorted(by:)` function but I seem only be able to do this within the `[Friend]` array. I want to use the variables from the other struct however.

Comment: Why do you have two structs?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Probably because it's a separate table in a DB

Comment: @PennyWise I would advise having one struct for this. Even if your underlying DB has these stored in two different tables, that's an implementation detail that should be contained by your database layer. The rest of your app logic shouldn't have to concern itself with joining friends to profileViews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to have a `ProfileViews` value as a property to `Friend`, or even to just have profile views as an `Int` property on `Friend`.

If that is not possible, then the easiest solution would be to create a dictionary of profile views and look them up on the fly.

```
// Create a dictionary that maps from user ids to ProfileViews:
let viewIndex = Dictionary(
    profileViews.map { views in 
        // views.id will be the key, views will be the value
        (views.id, views)
    }
    // If two views values exist with the same user ID, they will be added together
    uniquingKeysWith: { views1, views2 -> ProfileViews in
        ProfileViews(id: views1.id, views: views1.views + views2.views)
    }
)
// Sort friends by looking up the views in the viewIndex
let sortedFriends = friends.sorted(by: { friend1, friend2 -> Bool in
    (viewIndex[friend1.id]?.views ?? 0) < (viewIndex[friend2.id]?.views ?? 0)
})
```

Comment: Great solution! I suspect that OP's structs are database DTOs, in which case I expect the `id `to be unique. If that's the case,  OP can simplify this by instead using `Dictionary.init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)` (since no duplicate `id`s would be possible).

Comment: Oh btw, yo ucan replace the "// views.id will be the key, views will be the value" comment with: `(key: views.id, value: views)`, which makes it self documenting. Also, you can use `.lazy.map` to prevent the creation of the intermediate array that would usually be made by a call to `map`.

Comment: Beautiful! I went with this solution, very neat and performance is great. I love how much I learn every day from SO. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You likely want to join this information together permanently (by making `views` part of `Friend`), but if you want to keep them separate, you can still join them as needed exactly as you'd do a database JOIN:

```
struct FriendViews {
    let friend: Friend
    let views: Int
}

let friends: [Friend] = ...
let views: [ProfileViews] = ...


let friendViews = friends.map { (friend) -> FriendViews in
    let viewCount = views.first(where: { $0.id == 1 })?.views ?? 0
    return FriendViews(friend: friend, views: viewCount)
}
```

With that, you just need to sort friendViews using standard sorting tools that you seem to understand.

Comment: Thank you Rob! I went with Palle's solution, but I appreciate the input a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This solution maps Friend and ProfileView into a tuples before sorting them and then mapping them back.

Assuming two arrays, `friends` and `profiles`:

```
let sorted = friends.map { friend -> (Friend, Int) in return (friend, profiles.first(where! { $0.id == friend.id })?.views ?? -1) }
   .sorted { t1, t2 in t1.1 > t2.1 }
   .map { $0.0 }
```

Comment: This does a linear searching in `profiles` for every friend. Could be very slow for even small numbers of friends.

Comment: @Alexander yes but I was aiming for a good solution using the prerequisites given in the question, that is two arrays. Your comment above to the question is probably the best solution but as I said I was trying to answer the question as asked.

Comment: Filter would be marginally better, because it can finish early (stop searching once you've found what you're searching for), and because it prevents the allocation of the result array (and copying elements into it), but it's still going to have `O(profiles.count)` time complexity. You can use a dict to solve this. See Palle's answer.

Comment: Oops, yes, I did.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the further explanation here in the comments. I went with Palle's solution, but nonetheless I appreciate the effort a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution with some complexity analysis. Assuming `n = profileViews.count` and `m = friends.count`

```
// Count the total views each id has. We use a dictionary
// because dictionary lookup is O(n) compared to an array
// search, which is O(n).
// Complexity: 2 * O(n)
let totalViews = Dictionary(grouping: profileViews, by: { $0.id })
    .mapValues { pv in pv.reduce(0, {$0 + $1.views}) }

// Complexity: O(m log m)
let sortedFriends = friends.sorted { f0, f1 in
    let view0 = totalViews[f0.id] ?? 0 // O(1)
    let view1 = totalViews[f1.id] ?? 0 // O(1)
    return view0 > view1
}
```

Overral complexity: `2 * O(n) + O(m log m)`

Comment: Thank you for the input! I went with Palle's solution, but I love to see all the different possibilities.